# Как включить автоматическую отправку диагностических данных

Tags: google-play-console

На странице "Ошибки ANR и сбои" написано:

> В этом разделе представлены все данные об ошибках ANR и сбоях,
>   собранных с устройств Android, пользователи которых разрешили
>   автоматически отправлять данные для диагностики

И как этим пользователям разрешить отправлять эти данные?

Answer (score 0):

**Как включить или отключить функцию "Использование и диагностика"**

Вы можете включить эту функцию во время первоначальной настройки устройства или в любое другое время.

1. Откройте приложение "Настройки".
2. Нажмите Google, затем "Ещё" (три точки справа вверху - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]), затем Использование и диагностика.
3. Включите или отключите функцию Использование и диагностика.

Отключение этого параметра не повлияет на работу основных функций устройства (например, обновление Android) и на сбор информации другими приложениями.

[Ссылка](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6078260).

Comment: На телефоне эта функция включена, но в google play console ничего не приходит

Comment: А вот пришло, спасибо за ответ

Comment: Если приложение работает без ошибок и сбоев, то и показывать нечего. Я так предполагаю.